# Query all Machines with Printer ports -Like "*WSD*"

Tags: powershell

Some computers on my domain have had printers installed with the incorrect PortName. I have a list of all machines on my domain, and I can list all printers on a machine where the portname is like WSD using

```
Get-Printer -ComputerName $Computer | Where PortName -like "*WSD*"
```

But I want to have this run on every machine in my computer list and then create a CSV or text file with a list of every computer that has a printer with an incorrect port name.

This is what I have so far:

```
$ComputerList = Get-Content "c:\Temp\Computers.CSV"  

    foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList) {

        $WSD = Get-Printer -ComputerName $Computer | Where PortName -like "*WSD*" }
```

I don't quite know how to finish the script to accomplish what I want. Please let me know if I've made anything unclear. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, you should import data from a `.csv` using `Import-Csv` so you don't get problems with the headers.

Second, you are on a right track, but maybe try it like this:

```
$ComputerList = Import-Csv -Path "c:\Temp\Computers.CSV"
$WSD = @()

foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList.<EnterHeaderNameHere>)
{
  if (Get-Printer -ComputerName $Computer | Where-Object {$_.Portname -like "*WSD*"})
    {
      $WSD += $Computer
    }
}
```

This would check if the result of your query returns a hit, and if so it would append the ComputerName to the Array `$WSD`.

You can then just forward to the array to an file by using either `Out-File` or `Export-Csv` if you want.

e.g.:

```
$WSD | Out-File -Path "c:\Temp\WSD.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! So everything works except for the outputting of the computer names into the WSD.txt file. The WSD.txt file is being created but it is empty. For testing purposes my computer list only has 5 machines in it that I know are affected by the issue. If I run (Get-Printer -ComputerName $Computer | Where-Object {$_.Portname -like "*WSD*"}) against any of them individually then they return the printers with the wrong ports.

Comment: What do you mean with "they return the printers with the wrong ports."? If the query is wrong they shouldn't output anything. Also please be sure that you use `-like "*WSD*"` instead of `-like "WSD"`! The match does only work with `*`.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase. It seems that the WSD array either not outputting to the WSD.txt file or the array is not recording the computer names of the machines with the wrong port names. The WSD.txt file is empty when the script is complete. I tried Export-Csv as well and it did the same thing.

Comment: Ok lets do some basic debugging here: I don't know how you're input-file looks like. Be sure that the `foreach` gives the correct computername to the Command (just do some `echo $Computer` before the `if` to check). If the foreach is not working as intented try filling `$Computerlist` like you did in your question.

Comment: So my variables are looking good. If I echo $Computer then I get the first computer in my input file, and if I echo $Computerlist then I get a list of all of the computers in my input file.

Comment: Ofc it is not working... Well typos ftw (I should get some sleep..) ofc the line should look like this `$WSD += $Computer` not `$ComputerName`!

Comment: @DRuppe If an answers helped you don't forget to vote it up and mark it as correct (✅). This way others can identify good/helping answers :).

Answer (score 0):

Like he said import CSV is great. Since get-printer accepts comma separated lists (as denoted in help by the square brackets after string `<string[]>`  ), you could over simplify this.

```
$ComputerList = import-csv "c:\Temp\Computers.CSV"  
$WSD = Get-Printer -ComputerName $Computerlist.name | Where {$_.PortName -like "*WSD*" }
```

The .name after the variable will only spit out the computer names IF that column of the csv is titled "name" so you can alter your list to make the header "name". Or alter your code and change it from .name to whatever the fields actual name is.

The advantage to foreach loops in this situation is you could run the command as a job. And then when all jobs finish you could export the data into $wsd. But that's an entirely different write-up.

If you want it in a file, either put

```
$wsd | out-file c:\temp\computerlist.txt -append
```

Or just remove the variable wsd from your script and just pipe the main command into out-file

Comment: Thanks for the additional input! I'll put it to good use in the future.